# Linux http_proxy env vars and Firefox websocket connection

Tags: environment-variables, firefox, http, http-proxy

Is there an env var like `http_proxy` that will cause Firefox to make *WebSocket* connections through my proxy when "Use system proxy settings" is selected?

I'm running Linux and connecting to the internet through a corporate proxy.  If I configure the proxy settings directly in Firefox then all of my browsing works perfectly including, specifically, https://web.whatsapp.com.

However, if I set the following environment variables from `~/.profile`

```
export http_proxy='domain_user:password@http://ms_isa_server:8080'
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
export no_proxy=...
```

and then select "Use system proxy settings" in Firefox then everything still works perfectly *except* for WebSocket connections.  Specifically I get

`08:48:23.027 Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://w4.web.whatsapp.com/ws.1 a...`

when trying to use https://web.whatsapp.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1177909. Currently nobody is working on it.

Comment: The bug appears to have been closed/fixed. `RESOLVED FIXED in Firefox 56`